# Is there a way to monitor and record which applications have started recently?

Tags: android

I would like to know which applications the user has started within the last, say, 24hours. Is this possible?

Answer (score 3):

No, not possible (at least not without significant low-level work). Android doesn't keep usage history for applications as-is.