# how to keep track of which applications used most in android phone

Tags: android

HI ,

I need to keep track of installed applications which are used most and least in android device...  can anyone help me how to do this programmatically in android...??

My question some thing like , I need to capture the event/Intent which will/may happen when the apllication is launched every time...(like BOOT_COMPLETED will be brodcasted when device booted).

Comment: I doubt you can unless you have acess to the homescreen app's data (and can change the code)

Comment: I will clarify my question , I need to capture the event/Intent which will/may happen when the apllication is launched every time...(like BOOT_COMPLETED will be brodcasted when device booted).

Comment: That's not possible. Launching an application doesn't trigger a broadcast that you can read

Comment: Hi.. Did you manage to get the list of most used apps ? Do you mind sharing the same?

Answer (score 1):

This does not seem possible (unless the launcher/home screen or applications cooperate, e.g. through [instrumentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/testing/testing_android.html): but that would be strange in production code!). See also [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2114498/is-there-a-way-to-monitor-and-record-which-applications-have-started-recently).

Edited to add: indiscriminate capture of application launch intents is not AFAIK permitted. Were Android to add such functionality, the security implications would be significant (particularly if interception or modification were allowed!). What you are describing could be (partially) achieved by [replacing the home screen](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/Home/index.html).

Answer (score 0):

Some degree of usage information is collected already - from the launcher go to settings - about phone - battery use.

I think this resets every time you go on a charger, and don't know if its visible to ordinary apps.